# Did Windows break my LUKS encrypted disk?

Tags: linux, windows, encryption, luks, qubes

Primary OS is Qubes, secondary OS is Windows 10.

I have a disk `sda` with full disk encryption (LUKS). But now I don't see my ext4 partitions on that disk and there only is one NTFS partition with a size of 50 MbL

```
...
...
│   │   └─qubes_dom0-vm--sys--firewall--private                    253:87   0     2G  0 lvm   
│   └─qubes_dom0-swap                                              253:5    0   7.3G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
└─sdb1                                                               8:17   0   500M  0 part  /boot/efi
loop0                                                                7:0    0     1G  0 loop  
sda                                                                  8:0    0   5.5T  0 disk  
└─sda1                                                               8:1    0    50M  0 part
```

What should I do and are there any solutions for this situation?

Answer (score 1):

If you indeed used LUKS with the `sda` whole-disk device, then there was nothing unencrypted that Windows would recognize: as far as Windows was concerned, the disk was indistinguishable from one that was wiped by writing random data on it.

As a result, the Windows installer figured the disk was free to use.

Even though [a modern Windows installation requires multiple partitions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-biosmbr-based-hard-drive-partitions?view=windows-11), the Windows 10 allows you to only specify the location of the partition that becomes the system drive `C:\` (called "Windows partition" in the link above). The installation program will decide where the other hidden partitions will be located.

On systems with legacy BIOS-style boot, the installer will attempt to place at least the first partition (called "System partition" in the link above) to whatever it determines to be the first disk on the system: this is a heuristic guess to maximize the probability that the resulting installation will actually be bootable.

So, if you used LUKS on `/dev/sda`, I'm sorry to say that it looks like Windows overwrote at least the beginning of it. **Unless you have a backup of the LUKS header (that contains the encrypted master key for the encrypted volume) saved elsewhere, your data is most likely unrecoverable.**

---

Background: a legacy BIOS does not actually have a widely-supported standard way to tell the OS which disk(s) it considers bootable, nor the order in which it will attempt them.

The best any OS installer can do is to hope that the BIOS and the OS kernel the installer runs on have detected the disks in the same order, and the BIOS defaults to using the first disk for booting. Unfortunately, when booting from a USB media, the USB is presented by BIOS as the "first hard disk" for the purposes of booting, and so the disk ordering is temporarily altered from what it will be when booting from the hard disk. So the installation program must exclude the installation media, and then hope that the rest of the disk ordering is otherwise unchanged.

With UEFI, the OS installer will be able to actually inspect the boot order settings in a standard way and insert its bootloader in the boot order without overwriting existing OS bootloaders without the need to make any guesses.